# Magento Paypal order placed but incorrect redirect

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I am working with Magento V1.9.1.1.

I have entered the correct details for the sandbox account into the Website Payments Standard (Includes Express Checkout) "configure" area and enabled the solution.

When I put an item in the cart and pay with paypal, it takes you away to a paypal "pay site" to which I log in with the test buyer account and pay for the transaction. When I click the continue button it takes me back to my website to a review order page in which the user has to select a shipping method.

Once selected you then click the "place order button" it takes you to:

`http://www.domain.co.uk/checkout/cart`

with a message saying:

> Unable to initialize Express Checkout.
>   You have no items in your cart.

**Note:** The purchase is visible within the paypal developer sandbox. Also the order is placed correctly within Magento Sales->Orders.

It just seems to not take the user to the right place.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide your php error log and magento log?  Is your theme template overriding paypal/express ? You could try replacing your custom templates at `.../template/paypal/express` with those from `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/paypal/express`

Comment: Hi Slimshadddyyy I will upload my logs tonight when I get home. Essentially I have boiled down that it is due to the process, the user can click the pay with paypal button and it send the order off to paypal with no shipping details. The user submits the paypal order which goes through then returns to Magento to create the order in the Magento backend. This cannot work due to no shipping being selected. But the order has gone through paypal so now has no items to invoice (as they have already been invoiced)

Answer (score 2):

Unable to initialize Express Checkout.

This error is thrown when the following condition is true:

```
if (!$quote->hasItems() || $quote->getHasError())
```

It seems that the order is placed before the submit button is clicked and so the cart becomes empty and `!$quote->hasItems()` becomes true